Global foreign keys?
I'm using PostgreSQL with these tables:
CREATE TABLE transports (
    "company_id" smallint NOT NULL,
    "id" uuid NOT NULL,
    "measure_unit_id" uuid NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY transports ADD CONSTRAINT transports_pkey PRIMARY KEY (company_id, id);
ALTER TABLE ONLY transports ADD CONSTRAINT transports_measure_unit_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (company_id, measure_unit_id) REFERENCES measure_units(company_id, id);

CREATE TABLE measure_units (
    "company_id" smallint NOT NULL,
    "id" uuid NOT NULL,
    "name" character varying NOT NULL,
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY measure_units ADD CONSTRAINT measure_units_pkey PRIMARY KEY (company_id, id);

Everything works good.
Since the PK is a combo of company_id and id right now I'm adding the same rows in table measure_units with only column company_id being different.
Is there a way to tell Postgres that some rows are OK for each company_id and other not?
Example:
INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (1, new_uuid(), 'KG');
INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (1, new_uuid(), 'G');
INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (1, new_uuid(), 'M');
INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (1, new_uuid(), 'L');

INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (2, new_uuid(), 'KG');
INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (2, new_uuid(), 'G');
INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (2, new_uuid(), 'M');
INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (2, new_uuid(), 'L');

INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (3, new_uuid(), 'KG');
INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (3, new_uuid(), 'G');
INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (3, new_uuid(), 'M');
INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (3, new_uuid(), 'L');

I would like to use something like:
INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (ALL_COMPANIES, new_uuid(), 'KG');
INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (ALL_COMPANIES, new_uuid(), 'G');
INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (ALL_COMPANIES, new_uuid(), 'M');
INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") VALUES (ALL_COMPANIES, new_uuid(), 'L');

UPDATE:
I tried using company_id == 0 but I'm getting this error:
insert or update on table "transports" violates foreign key constraint "transports_measure_unit_id_fkey"

given this sql code I'm using:
ALTER TABLE ONLY public.transports ADD CONSTRAINT transports_measure_unit_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (company_id, measure_unit_id) REFERENCES public.measure_unit(company_id, id);

What I'm looking for here is to avoid the repeatd rows in the DB. Is there a way to tell PostgreSQL: the FK is (company_id, id) OR (0, id)?

What you could do is something like INSERT INTO "measure_units" ("company_id", "id", "name") SELECT company_id, new_uuid(), 'KG' from transports repeat for other names. As always test query preferably in BEGIN; <query>; COMMIT or ROLLBACK;

Not that way , what you can do is define a dummy company as all company and consider it for all the companies in your logic everywhere else ... otherwise it would be the best to insert a row for each company as Adrian mentioned

Thank you both. What I'm looking for here is to avoid the repeatd rows in the DB. Is there a way to tell PostgreSQL: the FK is (company_id, id) or (0, id) ?

Is this a multi-tenant database? So company_id is your partitioning key?

Yes, @Dai. Is a multi-tenant DB.

@FredHors Then this is fine - because company_id represents data ownership, so it makes sense for each company (i.e. Tenant) to have their own measurement-units rows (even if it looks redundant at-first) because if that Tenant/company wants to edit those rows for their own needs then it must not impact any other Tenant.

@Dai, I know. But sometimes I need some rows to be globals. Becuase for example "KG" is "KG" everywhere!

@FredHors How are these measure_units rows actually used, though? Can users edit them at all? If so, then you should keep your current design. If not, then you should remove the company_id column from measure_units entirely and add a second table: company_measure_units for tenant-specific units then.

Users should not be able to edit the global rows, but sholud be able to edit their own company specific rows.

@FredHors Please see the edit to my answer where I suggest a possible solution.


Since the PK is a combo of company_id and id right now I'm adding the same rows in table measure_units with only column company_id being different.

If your database is a multi-tenant database where tenants are meant to be segregated from each other (i.e. your company_id is a partitioning-key and represents a security boundary) then yes, this is fine despite it seeming silly.
The reason why I say it's fine is because the company_id value represents ownership of that data, which means that only users/clients belonging to that company_id can view, edit, and delete that data (and add new rows too).
By terrible analogy, this is as if you're the landlord of an apartment building and you're doing renovations and you don't like how you have to give each apartment its own toilet and because it's less effort just to build a single toilet and force all your tenants to share it.

Is there a way to tell Postgres that some rows are OK for each company_id and other not?

Given this is a multi-tenant database, I can't think of a reason why you'd want to do this (again, due to how you indicate ownership-of-data), but if you really did then you would:

Remove company_id from the PK, and use a single UNIQUE or IDENTITY column.
Make company_id a NULL-able column. FKs can have nullable columns.
Change your application's queries/views to return those rows where company_id IS NULL in addition to tenant-owned rows.

Or have shared/global units in TABLE measure_units but also per-Tenant units in a separate company_measure_units table - though this does complicate the FK situation.




Edit: From the comments:

Users should not be able to edit the global rows, but should be able to edit their own company specific rows

In which case, I'd do it like so:

First, a quick detour: you should avoid using column-names like "id" because it introduces ambiguity in queries when you use CTEs and JOINs. I think most people will agree it's best for column-names to be self-descriptive by indicating its the entity's type, so I use unit_id and transport_id here).

Because transports.company_id indicates the Tenant-owner of that transports row (so cannot be NULLable) it means you'll need another column for the FK to measure_units, but you can use a CHECK constraint to ensure company_id == unit_company_id OR unit_company_id IS NULL, thus ensuring the FK is valid.

The measure_units table's PK cannot contain NULLable columns, so I redefined the PK as using only unit_id, but I also added CONSTRAINT measure_units_ukey UNIQUE  which has the nullable company_id column included which allows for incoming composite FKs.

In a composite-key, generally speaking you should put the most specific column first, because it means index node traversal can locate specific rows in fewer steps.

A notable exception to this rule is when it's a clustering index/key and you want proximal locality of related rows - but doing this requires caution and a thorough understanding of Postgres' indexes.


Also read-up on using MATCH SIMPLE and NULLS NOT DISTINCT.

I think people should prefer varchar(n) over character varying, because omiting the n (max-length in chars) parameter means buggy software could store a gigabyte-sized blob of text in your name column (and yes, I've seen this happen in production and break everything and take hours to fix because anyone doing SELECT * FROM tbl to simply find out what's-going-on would logjam the server's HDDs and the network from them all inadvertently requesting a gigabyte worth of text data over and over, ugh. So I use varchar(255) as a sensible max-length.

You don't need to "double-quote-escape" every column-name: I find it adds unnecessary visual-clutter and makes it harder to read SQL, so only escape names that need escaping.

...though some people will argue that a name like name should always be escaped because eventually it's going to cause a syntax-error somewhere. I'll admit that for this particular name I'm on the fence myself.


I feel usng smallint for your Tenant-Identifier (company_id) is shortsighted: it means you'll only have 1 through 32,767, but I can confidently tell you that even if you only have a dozen actual tenants you'll still easily hit that 32,767 limit due to unrelated database operations that will increment the IDENTITY value - as well as things like system-tests, backups/restores, etc. I recommend you use int which gives you significantly more headroom. If you're using smallint because you want to save 2 bytes per row then I'll say you misunderstand how storage-costs in an RDBMS are not due to short-sighted microoptimizations like this.

I see you're using the uuid (i.e. GUIDs) type, which doesn't lend itself well to efficient storage in RDBMS. I recommend you consider switching to int. If you need to use uuid because these keys are coming from an external system then that's another discussion - but still consider using int for internal FKs.


Anyway:
CREATE TABLE companies (
    company_id smallint          NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,

    CONSTRAINT companies_pkey PRIMARY KEY ( company_id ),
);

CREATE TABLE measure_units (
    company_id smallint              NULL,
    unit_id    uuid              NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name       varchar(255)      NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT measure_units_pkey PRIMARY KEY ( unit_id ),
    CONSTRAINT measure_units_ukey UNIQUE      ( unit_id, company_id ),

    CONSTRAINT measure_units_company_fkey FOREIGN KEY ( company_id ) REFERENCES companies ( company_id ),

    /* These constraints are to ensure the `name` values are sensible: */
    CONSTRAINT measure_units_name_nonempty CHECK ( char_length( name ) > 0 ), /* Ensures the measurement-unit `name` is nonempty. */
    CONSTRAINT measure_units_uname UNIQUE ( name, company_id ), /* Ensures the measurement unit name is unique within the Tenant (so you won't have two units named "Kg"). Because of how `NULLS NOT DISTINCT` is configured, this will work fine for both company_id-specific rows and "global" rows where `company_id IS NULL`. */
);

CREATE TABLE transports (
    company_id      smallint NOT NULL,
    transport_id    uuid     NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,

    unit_company_id smallint     NULL,
    unit_id         uuid     NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT transports_pkey PRIMARY KEY ( transport_id, company_id ),

    CONSTRAINT transports_company_fkey FOREIGN KEY ( company_id               ) REFERENCES companies     ( company_id ),
    CONSTRAINT transports_unit_fkey    FOREIGN KEY ( unit_id, unit_company_id ) REFERENCES measure_units ( unit_id, company_id ) MATCH SIMPLE,

    CONSTRAINT transport_unit_fkey_same_company CHECK ( ( company_id = unit_company_id ) OR unit_company_id IS NULL )
);

So with the above schema-design:

When a transports row wants to reference a "global" measure_unit then company_id = 123, transport_id = IDENTITY, unit_company_id = NULL, unit_id = 456.
When a transports row wants to reference a private measure_unit then company_id = 123, transport_id = IDENTITY, unit_company_id = 123, unit_id = 789.
And the CHECK constraint prevents a transports row from breaking security by referencing a measure_unit owned by a different company_id except for "global" rows where company_id IS NULL.

Also: don't forget to verify your indexes over FK columns as Postgres does not create them implicitly.

Thanks, but if I use this query I get this error:
INSERT INTO "transports" ("company_id", "id", "unit_company_id", "unit_id")
VALUES (3, '01931234-7981-7c70-aa77-a2169d2d4113', NULL, '01931234-779a-7f83-a865-809fed660c37')

ERROR:  insert or update on table "transports" violates foreign key constraint "transports_unit_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (company_id, unit_id)=(3, 01931234-779a-7f83-a865-809fed660c37) is not present in table "unit".
Why?

@FredHors I cannot reproduce that error: here's a working example: https://dbfiddle.uk/zXjiuoEX

@FredHors Are you still having problems?

I'm trying right now again...

It works. I was using a wrong FKEY! THANKS 10000000 times!

@FredHors Phew - I'm glad I got you unstuck

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
